# Drupal7 GMAP module, show and hide certain markers

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7, view, google-maps-markers

I am using GMAP module on Drupal7 for Google Maps. I am using it with Views module.
Have created map view with markers from content type. Everything works fine.

Now I want to be able to show and hide some markers (not all) based on for example some category or any node field. How can I manipulate (just show and hide some of them) markers outside the view? Or maybe there is a possibility to do it within view?

Thanks.